# Automated flow of power bi reports from power bi service to sharepoint or onedrive

Tags: powerbi

I Want to have an environment where whenever a power-bi report (in .pbix format) is created or updated in a workspace in my power bi service, it will automatically be reflected in my sharepoint without any manual effort so that I can manage different versions of a report on organization level. Is there a way to achieve this automated connection between power bi service and sharepoint?

Tried to use sharepoint web-embedded option for pages but I guess it is not an option to make the connection automatic and requires multiple layers of manual effort for each page.

Comment: You want to share the dashboard on Sharepoint?

Comment: Hey @AmilaMGunawardana, yes would like to share it but I don't want any manual effort for this. I want to make the whole process automated.

Comment: Well you can follow this link to achieve it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-report-spo